# How to Filter List of Object using dynamic Properties in C#

Tags: c#, filter, dynamic, where-clause, listobject

I want to filter list of warehouseModels by FieldName which is "Code" and FieldValues which are "36" and "37" in this case by dynamically changing properties.
I hope I delivered my problem to you.

```
using ConsoleApp2;

void GetAll()
{
  //Need to filter this list of warehouse models
  IEnumerable<WarehouseModel> warehouseModels = new List<WarehouseModel>()
  {
    new WarehouseModel() { Code = "35", Name = "Name 35" },
    new WarehouseModel() { Code = "36", Name = "Name 36" },
    new WarehouseModel() { Code = "37", Name = "Name 37" },
    new WarehouseModel() { Code = "38", Name = "Name 38" },
    new WarehouseModel() { Code = "39", Name = "Name 39" },
    new WarehouseModel() { Code = "40", Name = "Name 40" }
  };

  //Need to filter above list by this FieldName  and FieldValue
  IEnumerable<PermModel> perms = new List<PermModel>()
  {
    new PermModel() { FieldName = "Code", FieldValue = "36" },
    new PermModel() { FieldName = "Code", FieldValue = "37" }
  };

  var newList = new List<WarehouseModel>();
  foreach (PermModel obj in perms.DistinctBy(x => x.FieldName))
  {
    //problem is here i need to solve.
    string propName = typeof(WarehouseModel).GetProperty(obj.FieldName).Name;
    var filteredWarehouseModels = warehouseModels.Where(x => x.propName == 
    obj.FieldValue).ToList();
    newList.AddRange(filteredWarehouseModels);
  }      
 }

 GetAll();
```

Comment: Are you trying to check if the FieldName is equal to a property in the WarehouseModel?

Comment: No, I want to filter using perms.FieldName  value which is "Code" in this case as x."FieldName" == perms.FieldValue

Comment: Could u give an example of expected result?

Comment: Expected result should return these new WarehouseModel() { Code = "36", Name = "Name 36" } and 
 new WarehouseModel() { Code = "37", Name = "Name 37" } as result of List<WarehouseModel>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void GetAll()
    {
        //Need to filter this list of warehouse models
        IEnumerable<WarehouseModel> warehouseModels = new List<WarehouseModel>()
        {
            new WarehouseModel() { Code = "35", Name = "Name 35" },
            new WarehouseModel() { Code = "36", Name = "Name 36" },
            new WarehouseModel() { Code = "37", Name = "Name 37" },
            new WarehouseModel() { Code = "38", Name = "Name 38" },
            new WarehouseModel() { Code = "39", Name = "Name 39" },
            new WarehouseModel() { Code = "40", Name = "Name 40" }
        };

        //Need to filter above list by this FieldName  and FieldValue
        IEnumerable<PermModel> perms = new List<PermModel>()
        {
            new PermModel() { FieldName = "Code", FieldValue = "36" },
            new PermModel() { FieldName = "Code", FieldValue = "37" },
            new PermModel() { FieldName = "Deed", FieldValue = "39" },

        };

        var newList = new List<WarehouseModel>();
        foreach (var perm in perms)
        {
            //problem is here i need to solve.
            string? propName = typeof(WarehouseModel).GetProperty(perm.FieldName)?.Name;
            var filteredWarehouseModels = warehouseModels.Where(x => perm.FieldName == propName && x.Code == perm.FieldValue).ToList();
            newList.AddRange(filteredWarehouseModels);
        }
    }
```

Is this your expected result?

Comment: please ignore string ? propName line of code, i've just tried to convert string value to property.  i just want to replace x.Code with perms.<FieldName> value which is string as x's property to compare it with perms.FieldValue value.

Comment: i want to treat string value as property in warehouse model.

Comment: You want to use the perm.FieldName as the property check in WareHouseModel?

Comment: Yes, want to use perms.FieldName as property and compare it with perms.FieldValue to filter warehouseModels.

Comment: That is what my code does. It checks if FieldName exists in WareHouseModel and if it exists it checks if FieldValue is also existing in WarehouseModel.Code value.

Comment: In my answer it shows that the third PermModel item with FieldName = "Deed" it does not get taken into the results because it's name is not Code.

Comment: Yes, of course i want this to be done.

Comment: So my solution should give u expected result